# Update Statement SQL error Incorrect Syntax SliderTitle and Where Statement

Tags: sql

I am having trouble with the following SQL statement.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select * 
From dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures 
WHERE SliderID =17 
GO

BEGIN TRAN

Update dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures  

SliderTitle = 'Racing to the Future',
SliderCaption = 'caption.',
SliderStart = '2014-09-30',
SliderEnd = '2014-10-7',
SliderPhoto = 'images/structure/RacingtotheFuture.png',
SliderLink = 'link'

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures 
WHERE SliderID = 17

-- COMMIT TRAN
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Here is the error message.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SliderTitle'.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the word `SET` in your `UPDATE` clause.  And potentially you might want to add a `WHERE` clause to that statement because as is, it will update all rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

The 'incorrect syntax' is the fact that a `SET` should be in your `UPDATE` statement - this should work:

```
USE HomePage

Select * From dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures WHERE SliderID =17 

GO

BEGIN TRAN

Update dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures  
Set SliderTitle='Racing to the Future',
SliderCaption='caption.',
SliderStart='2014-09-30',
SliderEnd='2014-10-7',
SliderPhoto='images/structure/RacingtotheFuture.png',
SliderLink='link'

SELECT * FROM dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures Where SliderID = 17

-- COMMIT TRAN
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Also, as [sgeddes pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131946/update-statement-sql-error-incorrect-syntax-slidertitle-and-where-statement/26132017#comment40958841_26131946) it would probably be wise to add a `Where` clause to your update statement, because this query will update all rows in the table.

I would guess that you actually want this:

```
SliderEnd='2014-10-7',
SliderPhoto='images/structure/RacingtotheFuture.png',
SliderLink='link'
Where SliderID=17 -- Limit it to only rows where SliderID=17

SELECT * FROM dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures Where SliderID = 17
```

Comment: +1 **and** one might also want to add the `WHERE SliderID = 17` clause to the update - otherwise, the **whole table** is updated to the new values!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your `UPDATE` statement:

1. You need a `SET` before listing the column values changes
2. You (probably) need a `WHERE` clause, unless you want to update *every row* in the table!
3. You need a semi-colon at the end

Try this:

```
...

UPDATE dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures SET -- Added SET
SliderTitle='Racing to the Future',
SliderCaption='caption.',
SliderStart='2014-09-30',
SliderEnd='2014-10-7',
SliderPhoto='images/structure/RacingtotheFuture.png',
SliderLink='link'
Where SliderID = 17; -- Added where clause and ";"

SELECT * FROM dbo.Site_tblSliderFeatures Where SliderID = 17; -- Added ";" here too

...
```